# Try-Catch with Stored Procedures in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have created a stored procedure with try-catch for deleting records.A message should be displayed if a record is deleted or if there is an error.The delete procedure works but the message is not being displayed.
Also,it asks me to input a value for @msg and @return when executing the procedure.

Here is my Stored Procedure code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[usp_AttendanceDelete]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AttendanceDelete] 
END 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AttendanceDelete] 
@A_ID int,
@msg        VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT,
@return     INT     OUTPUT

AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY

    DELETE
    FROM   [dbo].[Attendance]
    WHERE  [A_ID] = @A_ID

                   SET @msg = 'Attendance Deleted'
                   SET @return = 1
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        --SELECT error_message() as error
            SET @msg = 'Attendance Delete FAIL.'
            SET @return = 0
            GOTO fail_rollback
        END CATCH
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    RETURN
fail_rollback:
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Here is the code to execute the procedure:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_AttendanceDelete]
@A_ID ='234',
@msg='success', 
@return ='1'
```

Comment: Please add the code that shows how you're *calling* the procedure as well. I'd suspect the fault is there, not inside.

Comment: You're returning your `@return` and `@msg` as output parameters. You won't just "see" them after execution. You'll have to do something with them afterwards. Show us how you're calling your stored procedure and what you do with the output params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Query below

---

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[usp_AttendanceDelete]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AttendanceDelete] 
END 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AttendanceDelete] 
@A_ID int,
@msg VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT,
@return INT    OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Attendance] WHERE [A_ID] = @A_ID)
    Begin
    DELETE
    FROM   [dbo].[Attendance]
    WHERE  [A_ID] = @A_ID
    SELECT @msg = 'Attendance Deleted'
    SELECT @return = 1
    END
    ELSE
     Begin
    SELECT @msg='IN Put Record doesn''t exists'
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
         ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;


    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO

   DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(100),@return INt
   EXEC DBO.[usp_AttendanceDelete] 2,@msg OUT,@return OUT
   SELECT  @msg,  @return
```

Comment: The code works but I have not understood why you used @OUTPARAM when executing the procedure.

Comment: Those parameters are used to hold result from stored proc we can use any name as your requiment

Answer (score 3):

You can supply *variables* rather than *values* when calling the stored procedure and you need to remember to mark them as `output` also:

```
DECLARE @msg varchar(50)
DECLARE @return int
EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_AttendanceDelete]
@A_ID ='234',
@msg=@msg output,
@return=@return output
--Do something with msg/return
```